# Studying convergence of an integral at the vary of alpha

Tags: convergence-divergence, definite-integrals, improper-integrals

I need to understand this exercise from my math book: **study, at the vary of alpha belonging to R, the convergence of the following integral and then calculate the value for $a = 1$**.

$$
\int_0^{4} \frac{ \left( 5+3\sqrt{x} \right)(\arctan x)^{2a-1}   }{(4x-x^{2})^{\alpha} } \, dx
$$

Where $\alpha=\frac{1}{2}$

**The solution is the following:** 
For $x$ to $0^+$ the integral is convergent $\Rightarrow$ 
For $x$ to $\infty$ the integral is convergent because $\frac{5}{4^{a}x^{1-a}(1+o(1))}$ $\Rightarrow$ the integral is convergent for $a$ $>$ $0$

For $x$ to ${4^{-}}$ the integral is convergent $\rightarrow$ $\frac{10(\arctan4)^{2a-1}(1+o(1))}{2^{a}(4-x)^{a}(1+o(1))}$

I can't understand how to get to that point, the solution lacks explanation and I was not able to find anything online to help me, I only want to understand how to find when and where the integral is convergent or divergent, can anyone help me? I got to the point where I know that I need to calculate the limit where the integral is undefined, but I'm kind of stuck there. Can someone help me understand the solution?

Comment: This doesn't make sense to me.  This is a definite integral.  The answer will not be a function of $x$.  Also, I don't understand what you mean by "at the vary of $\alpha.$"  I took it to mean something like "as a function of $\alpha,$ but you say that $\alpha=\frac12,$ so that can't be right.  Can you clarify your question?

Comment: I'll just quote the line straight from my book: "Study, at the vary of alpha belonging to R, the convergence of the following integral"

Comment: What i'm trying to understand is the solution, i mean i don't know how to get to that solution by myself

Comment: Are you translating from some other language?  "Study at the vary of alpha" is not English.

Comment: I'm translating

Comment: I'm sorry, but your translation must be inaccurate.  I'm a native English speaker, and I can't understand your question.

Comment: @saulspatz well let me try this way: i need to study alpha on various points, so a=0, a>0 and a<1

Comment: Are you sure that $\alpha$ and $a$ are intended to be two separate variables?

Comment: No, alpha is the only variable, my bad